# Microsoft Teams desktop app does not invoke the authenticate successCallback or failureCallback functions specified by the integration app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm developing an app integrating with Microsoft Teams.  My app uses the `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate(...)` javascript function as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/auth). When calling this function, I specified my two callback functions for success and failure accordingly.

After my authentication workflow is completed, I call `microsoft.authentication.notifySuccess(...)`. After that, the expected behavior is that my success callback function as registered earlier should be invoked.  Similarly, in the case if I call `microsoft.authentication.notifyFailure(...)`, my failure callback function as registered earlier should be invoked.

The issue is that when working with the **desktop** version of the Microsoft Teams app, somehow neither my success nor failure callback function got invoked.

Other information that may be helpful:

- There is no issue with my app working with the web browser version of Microsoft Teams app (teams.microsoft.com).  The Microsoft Teams browser app properly invokes my registered success callback or failure callback functions.
- The version of the Teams desktop app is the most current one.
- OS Platform is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in v0.3 of the SDK.

It's fixed in with [this commit](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/commit/d281a2b250709ab92177e947d4455574abeca0e9) which should be part of the upcoming v0.4 release.

You can either downgrade to v0.2 or wait for v0.4 to release.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response and the workaround.  I will try v0.2 to unblock my development while waiting for the next release.